# Python Multi-Dimensional List - IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, list

I am sure this is simple, and I have read about a dozen posts about this same topic, but I still don't understand why this won't work...

```
banner = [[0 for i in xrange(60)] for i2 in xrange(60)]

def load_banner():
    file = open('banner', 'r')
    x = 0
    y = 0
    for line in file:
        for c in line:
            banner[x][y] = c
            y += 1
        x += 1
    pprint.pprint(banner)
```

Any ideas or suggestions are greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Because _len(line)>len(banner[::])_.

Comment: I thought that to at first, but when I open in nano, ctrl+c at the end of the line, its 57 columns, and 20 rows... I guess thats why I am lost...

Comment: @JeffreyL.Roberts You searching for every character, not line?

Comment: I just changed the xrange's to 200 each, and its still throwing an error, and its def not 200 rows or 200 columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing it's because you're not resetting the y variable.  So even if all your lines are less than 60 characters, y will keep growing and growing until it hits 60, then throws an IndexError.

Comment: btw I also fully endorse thefourtheye's solutions EXCEPT if you somehow specifically need to have the output in a 60x60 list (a slightly farfetched scenario)

Answer (score 1):

Don't define the list size hard coded, instead use `list.append` function, like this

```
banner = []
for row, line in enumerate(file):
    banner.append([])
    for c in line:
        banner[row].append(c)
```

Better, use list comprehension, like this

```
banner = [[c for c in line] for line in file]
```

Even better, use `list` function, like this

```
banner = [list(line) for line in file]
```

It can be written like this

```
with open("banner", "r") as in_file:
    print(list(map(list, in_file)))
```

Comment: I still have a few minutes before I can accept an answer, your solution is how I got it to work, but the other answer from zehnpaard was right on track too, I wish I could accept both

Comment: this is a much better way to write the code, though the other answer states specifically why what you had wasn't working

Comment: I concur, zehnpaard spotted the bug, also, he needs the points =]